# Error when plotting range from netcdf file of global temperature

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

Ive managed to download and plot the annual ocean temperature data from https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/OC5/woa18/woa18.pl

```
temp_WOCE <- nc_open("woa18_decav_t00_01.nc")
lon <- ncvar_get(temp_WOCE, varid = "lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(temp_WOCE, varid = "lat")
temp <- ncvar_get(temp_WOCE, "t_an")
depth <- ncvar_get(temp_WOCE, "depth")
```

There are 102 depth profiles (ranging from 0 - 5500m). I want to be able to

1. plot the range of temperature by latitude averaging over longitude and depth. [Similar to Figure 1 from this paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspb.2010.1295)

[image]

2. plot the range of temperature by depth by latitudinal bands (e.g. -60 to 90, -40 to -60, -20 to -40 etc.)

I can plot temp but it gives me a multiple global images of temperature as a function of depth (not what I need)

```
plot(temp)
```

But I need to plot temperature by latitude. Why does this give me an error

```
plot(temp~lat) 
Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : object is not a matrix

plot(temp~depth)
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'depth' not found
```

Comment: Note this is a 177Mb NCDF file (assuming its this: https://data.nodc.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/ncei/woa/temperature/decav/1.00/catalog.html?dataset=ncei/woa/temperature/decav/1.00/woa18_decav_t00_01.nc )

Comment: I get a different error for `plot(temp~lat)`, namely: `Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  :   variable lengths differ (found for 'lat')` because temp is 360x180x102 and lat is x180. Have you done something else with your data or missed out some `library` calls (including library(ncdf4))?

Comment: I have both library(raster) and library(ncdf4) before I run the code. dim(temp_WOCE) comes up as 360 x 180 x 102 and dim(depth) comes up as 102. So the temperature data is 360 (lon), 180 (Lat) x 102 (depth). When I just take the surface slice: surface <- temp_WOCE[ , ,1] and then create a raster I can plot a surface global map. But I can't seem to get all 120 to plot a map of temperature by latitude so I dont know what is going wrong or what I need to do to 'call' all 102 depth

Comment: and yes I do get the same error for lat. Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'lat'). I guess its because theres 180 lat points and 120 depth points.

Comment: Can you edit your question and update all that?